# how can I make a program to detect Arabic language with speech recognition on android studio project?

Tags: javascript, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, arabic

So, I have some projects where I should make speech recognition where the speech can recognize Arabic Language using android studio and java programming, to start it, I just want to know how to detect the Arabic Language with Speech Recognition? What libraries I can use for this project? Thanks in advance.

I have tried to add the speech recognition feature using Google Speech API in my project but still can't detect the Arabic Language. What should I do to overcome this? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: What about the language recognition feature?  https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/enable-language-recognition-speech-to-text